# Prefer way to allow multiple records for single id

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have spring boot application like below

```
@Entity
@Table( name="request_details")
@Data
public class RequestDetails{

@Id
@Column(name="data_id")
long id
String status;

@Lob
byte[] attachment;
}
```

previously requirement was only attachment was allowed per request, now requirement is change that there can be multiple attachment for single request, now I am unable to store multiple attachments for single request cause all has same *data_id* , what would be the best way amend this way?

should I use **isNew** method?
should I change implementation with isolating data_id from request? (it would be very big change given that I need to update database schema as well)

Comment: ID is the primary key of the table and there is exactly one record allowed per id. Maybe you want to have a look at https://www.w3schools.in/dbms/database-normalization/ for better understanding database behaviour and how to solve this problem.

Comment: @StefanD. I am aware of this, but now there is change in requirement so what would be best way

Answer (score 0):

One way is a second column which groups the distinct records like (pseudocode)

```
table request_details
  ID (primary key),
  attachment_nbr
  ... some other atributes
  attachment (LOB)

  unique constraint on ID, attachment_nbr
```

The grouping attributte attachment_nbr must be calculated in any way or obtained from a sequence number generator.

A better way is to use two seperate tables like (pseudocode)

```
table request
  ID (primary key)
  ... some other attributes

table attachments
  ID primary key
  ... some other atributes
  attachment (LOB)
  request_id (foreign_key request.ID)
```

Comment: but can unique constraint works along with PK?

Comment: Yes, it can! That are two different things: 1) Primary key is an implicit unique constraint. 2) Unique constraint over one or more columns. It requires that in the constrained columns no duplicate combination of values occure. No matter if there are any other indexes or constraints on the involved columns.

Comment: I tried to add but it doesn't work, cause when it sees there is PK available it will run update operation rather than insert

Comment: If there are existing records than you need a migration strategy: 1) add the new column, 2) populate values in the existing records and 3) set the newly required unique constrain. Don't know how to do this with spring because I'm an old fashion SQL guy ...